# Pass opportunity's stage value when stage value is edited

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

I have a VF page that uses `<apex:repeat>` to show a `List<Attachment>`, and I want the list to return different attachments based on `{!opportunity.stageName}` .

VF Page code :

```
<apex:page standardController="Opportunity"  extensions="QueryAttachments"> 
    <apex:repeat value="{!attachmentList}" var="att">
          <apex:image styleClass="bigImage" url="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, att.id)}" rendered="true"/>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Controller code:

```
public class QueryAttachments {

    public ApexPages.StandardController controller;
    public String stageName{get;set;}    
    public List <Attachment> attachmentList {
        get {
            return getAttachmentId();
        }
        set;
    }

    public QueryAttachments(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.controller= controller;
    }

    public List <Attachment> getAttachmentId () {
        System.debug('stageName : ' + stageName);
        return attachmentList = [Select Id,Name,ParentId,Parent.Name,CreatedDate from Attachment Where Description =: stageName ]; 
    }
}
```

I can retrieve `value="{!opportunity.stageName}"` in VF, what I want is to pass it to `QueryAttachments` controller and query based on it's value.

I don't want to use `apex:actionFunction` or `apex:commandButton`, I only want to pass `opportunity.stageName` when the stage on opportunity sObject is saved and show the associated attachments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to explicitly pass anything between your visualforce and your controller extension here. The `standardController`, which you're placing into `this.controller` in your constructor has a copy of the same `Opportunity` that you have access to in the visualforce page through merge expressions like `{!Opportunity.StageName}`.

You can access this by using the `getRecord()` method of `ApexPages.StandardController`.

A brief example would be this

```
public class MyExtension{
    private Opportunity theOpp;

    public MyExtension(ApexPages.StandardController con){
        // The getRecord() method returns a generic SObject.
        // Typecasting is required if you want to store the record
        //   in a 'concrete' SObject like Opportunity
        theOpp = (Opportunity)con.getRecord();
    }

    public List<Attachment> getAttachments(){
        // Standard caveats apply here
        // theOpp will only contain fields referenced on your visualforce page
        return [SELECT Id FROM Attachment WHERE someField = :theOpp.StageName];
    }
}
```

Comment: `theOpp.StageName` will return an error _SObject row was retrieved via SOQL without querying the requested field_ , I had to query Opportunity object to get the stageName since theOpp object only had `id` as an attribute.     



`public List <Attachment> getAttachmentId () {
        String stages = [Select stageName from Opportunity Where Id =: theOpp.Id limit 1].get(0).stageName;
        return attachmentList = [Select Id from Attachment Where Description =:  stages ]; 
    }`


Other than that it works like a charm !

Comment: @user46892 Like I mentioned in my example code,  `theOpp` only has fields available that you use on your visualforce page. You could avoid the query by including `<apex:variable var="throwaway" value="{!Opportunity.StageName}"/>` somewhere in your visualforce page (which would cause your page to reference the field without rendering some HTML to also display the value).